# REACT Jest - Test suite failed to run

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have created sample react project and added JEST, enzyme dependencies to test my component. But getting below error while running test suite:
**ERROR:**
 Cannot find module 'components/Add' from 'App.js'

```
However, Jest was able to find:
    'components/Add.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

However, Jest was able to find:
    './App.css'
    './App.js'
    './App.test.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

  1 | import React from 'react';
> 2 | import Add from 'components/Add';
    | ^
  3 |
  4 |
  5 | function App() {

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:2:1)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.035s
Ran all test suites.

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue, will be happy to share more details.

Comment: It's because Jest know where 'components' is, please look at this and configure it in your jest.config.js https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a relative import instead?

```
import Add from './components/Add';
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The way your imports are written, you're probably using aliases for your paths. If you're using webpack, check webpack.config.json for `resolve.alias` field to confirm this.

If you do have aliases set up, You will have to add them to your jest configurations also. This is done using [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string). For example,

```
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/PATH_TO_COMPONENTS/$1",
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, i am using alias in webpack config. will add above config in jest configuration as per you suggested and then let you know if it's works.

Comment: with above config the original error is resolved but facing below error, unable to find the solution: